# Proguard doesn't work when export with Eclipse ADT plugin R19

Tags: android, adt, proguard

When I export my application through `Export > Export Android Application` or through `Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package`, I just cannot get Proguard work.

All I know about how to enable Proguard is to uncomment the line

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

in `project.properties`.

And I tried putting my configuration file there, too. Won't work either.

The `classes.dex` file in the exported package contains the name of class private methods such as `onConfirmButtonClicked`. So there's more than 99% chance that Proguard didn't do its work.

After that I put some random characters in the `proguard-project.txt` file, but I didn't get any error. The verbose output of the build didn't refer Proguard at all.

I wonder what's wrong there.

Comment: How do you see that classes.dex file - contained any particular method? It seems to contains junk characters even without proguard.

Answer (score 0):

Proguard does its work when you export your project into an .apk file, and you should put the configuration you need in a file (.cfg) and you point to that file in your **project.properties**

```
proguard.config=${dir}\YOURCONFIGFILE.cfg
```

and in that config file you should tell proguard to keep all the crucial elements in your project. For exemple :

```
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars /usr/local/java/android-sdk/platforms/android-9/android.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {    
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

Hope this helps!